# C# "System" version update

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm in C# in Visual Studio running 2015 Update 3.

I'm using a dll that I made myself for the backend of a system, and in the references of the project, one shows the "System" as Version 2.0.5 and the project being used as a dll shows it as 4.0.0. I believe this is the cause of a conflict that is preventing me from running this app. How do I update just the system version or even specify it so I can make them the same?

Comment: more information: 

I'm using Xamarin to build an app on Android. When building an Android app, it defaults to System Version 2.0.5, but when building a Library, it defaults to 4.0.0. 

Is this just an resolvable issue and I cannot have a single backend for this windows and android app? (I realize this would be a bad idea for an open released android app, but it's meant only to be used locally on a closed system; no part of this app will go on an open store)

Comment: System version 2.0.5.0 is the version referenced by certain portable class library profiles. If you are using Xamarin this version is probably correct. Without more information it is hard to tell what your problem is. Can you explain the conflict you are seeing and what projects you have and how they interrelate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go to the references of your project containing the old reference, remove System and add it with version 4.0.0.0. However, you should also check that target .NET framework versions match (maybe the older dll is obtained compiling against .NET framework 2.0 and the newest one against .NET framework 4.0).

In order to find out the cause that is preventing you from running the application (you should provide what is happening), an useful tool is [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which will show the exact assemblies that the application is trying to load (fully qualified assembly names).

Comment: How do I add version 4.0.0.0?

Comment: If you go to References of your projects, Add Reference, filter for System, what do you see? If version is less than 4.0.0.0, check project's target framework: Project properties -> Target framework.